# Can't check if a string(token list) type macro in a sequence in LaTeX3?

Tags: conditionals, latex3, strings, auxiliary-files, l3seq

This is my first time on TeX Stack Exchange, so please forgive me if I unintentionally offend anyone.

Compile Environment(using `pdflatex` to compile):

```
WSL: x86_64 Linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
TeX Live: 2023/Arch Linux
```

The example folder files as follows:

```
├── file.txt
└── main.tex
```

`file.txt` contains the following:

```
Hello World
```

Here is the `mwe` (source `main.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}



\ExplSyntaxOn
% file content in line by line (seq)
\ior_new:N \g_file_stream
\cs_new_protected:Nn \File_read_lines:n{
    \ior_open:Nn \g_file_stream { #1 }
    \seq_gclear_new:N \g_current_aux_hash_seq
    \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_file_stream
    {
        \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_current_aux_hash_seq{ \tl_trim_spaces:n { ##1 } }
    }
    \ior_close:N \g_file_stream
}

% check
\NewDocumentCommand\Test{ m }{
    % write hash to external_code.aux
    \str_new:N \file_current_hash_str
    \file_get_mdfive_hash:nN { #1 }\file_current_hash_str
    \sys_shell_now:x {echo~ "\file_current_hash_str" >> external_code.aux}

    % read hash seq from file external_code.aux
    \File_read_lines:n {external_code.aux}

    % check if in
    \noindent The ~ \textbackslash seq_if_in:NnTF~ result~ is:\par
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_current_aux_hash_seq{\seq_item:Nn \g_current_aux_hash_seq{1}}{In\par}{Not~ In\par}
        \item \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_current_aux_hash_seq{\str_use:N \file_current_hash_str}{In\par}{Not~ In\par}
        \item \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_current_aux_hash_seq{B10A8DB164E0754105B7A99BE72E3FE5}{In\par}{Not~ In\par}
    \end{itemize}

    % direct output results
    while~ the~ print~ result~ is~ the~ same
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbackslash file_current_hash_str~is:\str_use:N \file_current_hash_str\par
        \item \textbackslash seq_item:Nn \textbackslash g_current_aux_hash_seq\{1\}~ is~:\seq_item:Nn \g_current_aux_hash_seq{1}\par
    \end{itemize}

    cs~ meaning~ cmd~ result:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \cs_meaning:N \file_current_hash_str
        \item \cs_meaning:N \g_current_aux_hash_seq
    \end{itemize}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \Test{file.txt}
\end{document}
```

The output pdf like:
[image]

My attempt
I have try setting the variable `\file_current_hash_str` using `\str_new`, `\seq_new`, `tl_new`, but none of these works. but i find when i set `\file_current_hash_str` by

```
\newcommand{\cmdseq}{ Hello }
```

and here is the `mwe` of my trying

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% set seq
\seq_new:N \test_seq 
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \test_seq{Hello, world, prime, bye}

% test if in
\newcommand{\cmdseq}{ Hello } 
\seq_if_in:NVTF \test_seq{\cmdseq}{In\par}{Not~ In\par}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

which generate the output:

[image]

I want to know if there is a way to solve this problem, Thanks.

Comment: Use `\token_to_str:N` or `\token_to_str:c` to print the name of a control sequence within the document. This is more convenient than `\textbackslash` or `\c_backslash_str`.

Comment: Aside. You shouldn't be using `\file_current_hash_str` to store your data, rather a proper-named (internal) variable in your own module, say `\l__zpd_current_hash_str`

Comment: besides the variable name, also your functions have problematic names for l3 naming conventions. They should be named something like `\zpd_file_read_lines:n` (if `zpd` was the name of your module) instead of `\File_read_lines:n`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construct

```latex
\seq_if_in:NnTF \g_current_aux_hash_seq{\str_use:N \file_current_hash_str}
```

checks if the sequence contains *exactly* `\str_use:N \file_current_hash_str`. Instead, you want to check if the sequence contains the value of the string:

```latex
\seq_if_in:NVTF \g_current_aux_hash_seq \file_current_hash_str
```

You also need to watch category codes. You have a `str` from the hash function, but if you write to a file and read back using `\io_map_stream:Nn`, in values will be tokenized using normal catcodes. So use `\io_str_map_stream:Nn` to do the job:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
Hello world
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \g__zpd_file_ior
\seq_new:N \g__zpd_file_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \zpd_file_read_lines:n
  {
    \ior_open:Nn \g__zpd_file_ior {#1}
    \seq_gclear:N \g__zpd_file_seq
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g__zpd_file_ior
      {
        \seq_gput_right:Ne \g__zpd_file_seq
          { \tl_trim_spaces:n {##1} }
      }
    \ior_close:N \g__zpd_file_ior
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \zpd_file_read_lines:n { e }

\seq_new:N \g__zpd_hash_str
\NewDocumentCommand\Test{ m }
  {
    \file_get_mdfive_hash:nN {#1} \g__zpd_hash_str
    \sys_shell_now:e { echo~ "\g__zpd_hash_str" >> \jobname.txt.hash}

    % read hash seq from file external_code.aux
    \zpd_file_read_lines:e { \jobname.txt.hash }
    \seq_show:N \g__zpd_file_seq
    \str_show:N  \g__zpd_hash_str

    % check if in
    The ~ \textbackslash seq_if_in:NnTF~ result~ is:\par
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \seq_if_in:NVTF \g__zpd_file_seq \g__zpd_hash_str
          {In\par}{Not~ In\par}
    \end{itemize}

}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \Test{\jobname.txt}
\end{document}
```

(I've tided up naming, etc.)

Comment: See note under the question about the variable name: I've used the one from the question for clarity, but it is not right

Comment: when I type the code `\item \seq_if_in:NVTF \g_current_aux_hash_seq\file_current_hash_str{In\par}{Not~ In\par}` into my source code, the output is still `Not In` ? Can this solution run correctly on your local computerr ? If so, could you please give me the `mwe` on your local? thanks.

Comment: @zongpingding Updated with a full example addressing the `str` aspect too

Comment: This code perfectly solved my issue. Thank you!